# How to fetch all value of an element from xml column in SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have the following xml column in sql :

```
Create table dbo.sampleXML( ID int identity(1,1) primary key,
Name char(10) not null,
content xml null)
go

insert into dbo.sampleXML (Name,content) values ('ss',CAST('<Employee>
<FirstName> ss </FirstName>
<LastName> nn </LastName>
<Gender> Male </Gender>
<Age>31</Age>
</Employee>

' as xml))
insert into dbo.sampleXML (Name,content) values ('xx',CAST('<Employee>
<FirstName> xx </FirstName>
<LastName> yy </LastName>
<Gender> Male </Gender>
<Age>3</Age>
</Employee>

insert into dbo.sampleXML (Name,content) values ('dd',CAST('<Employee>
    <FirstName> ss </FirstName>
    <LastName> dd </LastName>
    <Gender> Female </Gender>
    <Age>30</Age>
    </Employee>
```

Tried to read all values from xml whose gender is male. Tried this

```
select content.query ('/Employee/FirstName') as FirstName,content.query('/Employee/Gender[1]') as Gender from dbo.sampleXML where content.value ('/Employee/Gender','varchar(10)')='Male'
```

But facing the error "select content.query ('/Employee/FirstName') as FirstName,content.query('/Employee/Gender[1]') as Gender from dbo.sampleXML where content.value ('/Employee/Gender','varchar(10)')='Male'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question I take, that you want to *filter* your XML to show only *male* people. You achieve this with a filter predicate in `.nodes()`.

Attention: The compare string is "(space)Male(space)" because your data is this way.

```
Create table dbo.sampleXML( ID int identity(1,1) primary key,
Name char(10) not null,
content xml null)
go

insert into dbo.sampleXML (Name,content) values ('ss',CAST('<Employee>
<FirstName> ss </FirstName>
<LastName> nn </LastName>
<Gender> Male </Gender>
<Age>31</Age>
</Employee>' as xml));
insert into dbo.sampleXML (Name,content) values ('xx',CAST('<Employee>
<FirstName> xx </FirstName>
<LastName> yy </LastName>
<Gender> Male </Gender>
<Age>3</Age>
</Employee>' as xml));
insert into dbo.sampleXML (Name,content) values ('dd',CAST('<Employee>
<FirstName> ss </FirstName>
<LastName> dd </LastName>
<Gender> Female </Gender>
<Age>30</Age>
</Employee>' as xml));

SELECT ID
      ,Filtered.Males.value('Gender[1]','varchar(max)') AS Gender 
      ,Filtered.Males.value('FirstName[1]','varchar(max)') AS FirstName 
      ,Filtered.Males.value('LastName[1]','varchar(max)') AS LastName
      ,Filtered.Males.value('Age[1]','int') AS Age
FROM dbo.sampleXML 
CROSS APPLY content.nodes('/Employee[Gender=" Male "]') AS Filtered(Males);
```

The result

```
ID  Gender  FirstName   LastName    Age
1    Male    ss           nn        31
2    Male    xx           yy        3
```

Answer (score 3):

1) You need to specify the ordinal at each level of your xpath expression when you use .value

2) You have extra spaces inside the Gender literals, so you need to include them in the where clause, i.e. ' Male '

```
select content.query ('/Employee/FirstName') as FirstName,content.query('/Employee/Gender[1]') as Gender 
from dbo.sampleXML 
where content.value ('/Employee[1]/Gender[1]','varchar(10)')=' Male '
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message you should've seen suggests, `value()` XML method requires an XPath/XQuery that guaranteed to return singleton value or empty. `/Employee/Gender[1]` returns first `Gender` child in `Employee`, while it isn't guaranteed that there is only one `Employee` in the XML.

That said, you need to put index after `Employee` and `Gender` to guarantee a singleton or empty return value, or alternatively, wrap the entire XPath with parentheses and return only the first matched like this :

```
(/Employee/Gender)[1]
```

Furthermore, `Gender` elements value in your sample XML has whitespaces around so it won't be matched by `'Male'` filter. You might want to use `LTRIM(RTRIM())` to remove surrounding spaces since XPath `normalize-space()` isn't available in SQL Server XPath/XQuery.

Comment: The OP did not want to take the first male person but to filter all male entries...

Comment: Judging from OP's sample data, there is only one employee in the XML column in a table row... don't know about his real data tho

Comment: Yes, true... My bad... Happy coding!